# generating items from json file in robot framework

Tags: json, robotframework

At the moment I have a custom library to read a json file and output a list. For example

```
def get(f):
  with open(f) as fd:
    data=json.load(fd)
  return [ k for k in data['d']['a'] ]
```

Then in RF, I call it like this

```
@{items}=    get     "f.json"
```

Is there a way I can do this natively in Robotframework without my custom function? I looked thru HttpLibrary but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: is "f.json" a local file?

Comment: yes. its a local file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible. Here is how to do it without HttpLibrary, but using OperatingSystem Robot Framework Library (to open the file), and json Python library (to load the JSON):

```
*** Settings ***
# Import Robot Framework Libraries
Library  OperatingSystem
# Import Python Library
Library  json

*** test cases ***
mytest
    # no need for double quote around file name. Variables are string by default
    @{item} =    get_in_robot    f.json

*** Keywords ***    
get_in_robot
    [Arguments]    ${file_path}
    ${data_as_string} =    Get File    ${file_path}
    ${data_as_json} =    json.loads    ${data_as_string}
    # looking into the dict at ["d"]["a"] will return the list
    [Return]    ${data_as_json["d"]["a"]}
```

Hope this helps